# Electric Work and Electric Potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, charge, potential, work

Could someone answer this with an explanation? I have a guess that it is the third path that requires the most work since it is the longest and most zig-zaggy of them to reach point b, but I'm not sure how this relates to electric work. Thank you so much.

[image: A Charge Is Moved From Point a to Point b In Three Different Paths In The Presence Of a Point Charge. Which Path Required The Most Work?]

Answer (score 1):

Electrostatic fields are conservative which means that work done in moving  a particle in field of another particule is independent of path chosen ,it only depends upon the initial and final position of particle so work done is same for all